# Azure Tables HTTP Rest Authorization Header Inconsistent

Tags: httpclient, blazor-webassembly, azure-table-storage, blazor-hybrid

I am using a HttpClient to make requests to Azure TableStorage. The code I am using to generate the authorisation header using SharedKeyLight method is:

```
    string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n/{1}/{2}",
            date,
            account,
            Table
        );

    var hasher = new HMACSHA256(sharedKey);

    string signedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
    string authorizationHeader = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKeyLite", account, signedSignature);
```

where `date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and account is a string with the azure storage account name and table is a string with the table name.

This works fine as is for a POST method to `https://[AzureURL]/[TableName]`

[UPDATE] stringToSign for the POST methods which works is:

"Sun, 01 Jan 2023 16:52:15 GMT\n/[AccountName]/Benefits"

For a GET request to a url with a querystring (say) `https://[AzureURL]/[TableName]()?$filter=(PartitionKey%20eq%20'QueryValue')` I have to use the table name and ():

```
string stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n/{1}/{2}",
        date,
        account,
        Table + "()"
    );
```

This makes some sense as the table is suffixed with () before the ? for the querystring to start.

[UPDATE] the stringToSign for the GET requests that works is:

"Sun, 01 Jan 2023 16:58:05 GMT\n/[AccountName]/Benefits()"

For DELETE and PUT methods to (say) `https://[AzureURL]/[TableName](PartitionKey='{PartitionKeyValue}', RowKey='{RowKeyValue}')` neither of these variants of the signature string seem to work and I get a response from Azure of

> Forbidden - Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the
> value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
> signature

Any idea of what I might need to do to form an appropriate signature string for a DELETE or PUT request?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the value of `stringToSign` for the failed requests.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav - I have edited the post - the Delete and PUT methods work with neither of the `stringToSign` values [i.e. with or without the parenthesis at the end].

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that your `DELETE` and `PUT` requests are not working when the value of canonical resource in `stringToSign` is `/account/table(PartitionKey='{PartitionKeyValue}', RowKey='{RowKeyValue}')`?

Comment: yes - a DELETE request with a url `https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey='myPartitionKey', RowKey='myRowKey')` [as taken from MS documentation example] wont authorize with an authorization request header signed in the same way as a GET or a POST request. I assumed that the signing method required for a GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request would be identical?

Comment: Please try by url encoding the canonical resource. Something like `/account/table(PartitionKey='{PartitionKeyValue}',%20RowKey='{RowKeyValue}')`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! it was that %20 I had tried playing around with encoding on the url but never crossed my mind that the canonical resource would need to have any encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#shared-key-lite-and-table-service-format-for-2009-09-19-and-later), you would need to use URL encoded path of the resource.

---

[image]

---

Please specify the canonical resource with the following while constructing the string to sign:

```
/account/table(PartitionKey='{PartitionKeyValue}',%20RowKey='{RowKeyValue}')
```